# change the text orientation (from vertical to horizontal) of the vertical axis of an excel chart with multi-level labels (work situation, Temporality)

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to bold the professional situations on the vertical axis of my chart and also make the text orientation horizontal, but I haven't found anything conclusive on the subject even after trying with VBA (to tell the truth, I'm a beginner in VBA...).

Here's what the original table and graph look like :

[image]
[image]

```
Sub FormatAxisLabels()
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim ax As axis
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Remplacez "NomDuGraphique" par le nom de votre graphique
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("BASE")
    Set ax = cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
    
    ' Formatez l'axe des catégories
    With ax
        .TickLabelOrientation = xlTickLabelOrientationHorizontal
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tried this code but it doesn't recognize the name of my chart (not sure if that's the only problem) and to be honest I'd prefer not to have to put a title on my chart.

Thank you all for your help

Sincerely

N.O

Comment: To confirm the name of your chart, select the chart, and then look at the Name Box to the left of the formula bar.

Comment: To bold the vertical axis try `ax.ticklabels.font.bold = true`